# how to eliminate bitvector arithmetic in Z3

Tags: z3, bitvector

I am trying to use the z3 to eliminate the expression

```
not ((not x) add y)
```

which equals to

```
x sub y
```

by this [code](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/NG8L):

```
(declare-const x (_ BitVec 32))
(declare-const y (_ BitVec 32))
(assert (= (bvnot (bvadd (bvnot x) y)) (bvsub x y)))
(check-sat)
(simplify (bvnot (bvadd (bvnot x) y)))
```

I want to get the result like:

```
sat
(bvsub x y)
```

However, the result is:

```
sat
(bvnot (bvadd (bvnot x) y))
```

Would some one help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can prove that `(bvnot (bvadd (bvnot x) y))` is equivalent to `(bvsub x y)` using the following script.

```
(declare-const x (_ BitVec 32))
(declare-const y (_ BitVec 32))
(assert (not (= (bvnot (bvadd (bvnot x) y)) (bvsub x y))))
(check-sat)
```

In this script, we used Z3 to show that `(not (= (bvnot (bvadd (bvnot x) y)) (bvsub x y)))` is unsatisfiable. That is, it is not possible to find values for `x` and `y` such that the value of `(bvnot (bvadd (bvnot x) y))` is different from the value of `(bvsub x y)`.

In Z3, the `simplify` command just applies rewriting rules, and it ignores the set of asserted expressions. The `simplify` command is much faster than checking satisfiability using `check-sat`. Moreover, given two equivalent expressions `F` and `G`, there is not guarantee that the result of `(simplify F)` will be equal to `(simplify G)`. For example, in Z3 v4.3.1, the simplify command produces different results for `(= (bvnot (bvadd (bvnot x) y)` and `(bvsub x y)`, although they are equivalent expressions. On the other hand, it produces the same result for `(= (bvneg (bvadd (bvneg x) y)` and `(bvsub x y)`.

```
(simplify (bvnot (bvadd (bvnot x) y)))
(simplify (bvneg (bvadd (bvneg x) y)))
(simplify (bvsub x y))
```

[Here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/U7TN) is the full script for the examples above.

BTW, these examples are much more readable if we use the [Z3 Python interface](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/xGWn).

```py
x, y = BitVecs('x y', 32)
prove(~(~x + y) == x - y)
print simplify(x - y)
print simplify(~(~x + y))
print simplify(-(-x + y))
```

Finally, Z3 has more complex simplification procedures. They are available as *Tactics*. The tutorials in [Python](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/tutorial/strategies) and [SMT 2.0](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/tutorial/strategies) format provide additional information.

Another possibility is to modify the Z3 simplier/rewriter. As you pointed out, `not x` is equivalent to `-x -1`. We can easily add this rewrite rule: `not x --> -x - 1` to the Z3 rewriter.
As an example, [in this commit](http://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/8515044f8bec), I added a new option called "bvnot2arith" that enables this rule. 
The actual implementation is very small (5 lines of code).

Comment: Thanks for replying. But in fact, I have no confusion about `bvnot` and `bvneg`. What I need here **IS** the bitwise-not operation. As we all know, in Bit-vector arithmetic, `-x = not x + 1 => not x = -x - 1`, Thus, `not ((not x) + y) = -((-x - 1) + y) - 1 = x + 1 - y - 1 = x - y`. However, the _Tactics_ you mentioned really help me out, according to [Custom simplifiers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13802651/custom-simplifiers), the question you've answered before. It seems like I need a **custom Tactics** here, Right? Anyway, Thanks for your help.

Comment: My bad, I will fix the answer.

Comment: I also added the rewriting rule `not x --> -x -1` as an example on how to hack the Z3 rewriter (http://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/8515044f8bec)