# Does Z3's simplify() method support absorption law?

Tags: z3, solver

Supposed I have a BoolExpr in the form of

```
a & (a | b) or a | (a & b)
```

and I want to simplify it to

```
a
```

by calling simplify(). It doesn't work.

Also, for a constraint like

```
(a | b) & (b | a)
```

simplify() can not turn it into the simplest form

```
(a|b) or (b|a).
```

Is there a workaround way?

@Nikolaj Bjorner: Thanks for your help and I have one more question:

Here is my original constraint:

```
Goal: (goal
  (or (> (type o) 2) (= (type o) 1))
  (or (= (type o) 1) (> (type o) 2)))
```

Here is the simplified version(by ctx-solver-simplify):

```
(or (= (type o) 1) (not (<= (type o) 2)))
```

The actual constraint I am expecting is:

```
(or (= (type o) 1) (> (type o) 2))
```

and I don't want to introduce any negation. What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default simplifier seeks only rewrites that are cheap.
There is a different simplifier that you can invoke as a tactic.
It simplifies the goals you describe.
For example:

```
(declare-const a Bool)
(declare-const b Bool)
(assert (or a (and a b)))
(apply ctx-solver-simplify)
```

It may return several subgoal that need to be re-assembled to a formula.
The Z3 tutorial on rise4fun.com describes tactics.

The ctx-solver-simplify does limited context-dependent rewriting. It is still incomplete.
It does not produce canonical normal forms (two formulas that are equivalent may simplify to
two different formulas).

Comment: Can we avoid generating negation during simplification?

Comment: I think I need to modify the source code to avoid negations based on 
Leonardo's reply: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15876712/adjusting-simplify-tactic-in-z3

Comment: One more question: It takes about 10,000 ms to simplify the above constraint for 10,000 times. Is this a normal speed? Thanks.